# What does "mirror in my bathroom" mean?

Tags: meaning, mauro-mevlud-martino, lonely-man-full-of-love

In the following passage from *Lonely Man Full of Love* by Mauro Mevlud Martino, what does "mirror in my bathroom" mean?

> A: ‘’Are you quieter and lonelier than me, Rachel?’’
>
> B: ‘’Perhaps, Martin. Perhaps. I want to be good to myself. **I have a
> mirror in my bathroom.**’’
>
> A: ‘’I think the main character in my novel Weeping Willow Trees was
> you.’’

Does it literally mean that she (B) has a mirror in her bathroom? Or does it mean that she spends most of her time looking at the mirror? Or does it have a connotation that she (B) suffers from narcissism?

Comment: Why wouldn't she just mean that she can see herself?

Comment: I think this might be opinion-based, or belong to the Literature SE, but I think maybe "I have a mirror in my bathroom" means "I do not want to live in a way that makes me look bad or unhappy, because I will see it in the mirror which I have in my bathroom".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey this makes more sense.

Comment: We can use plain statements to explain something. I don't visit casinos or strip clubs. I have a wife and children.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHarvey. The sentence's plain meaning is that she has a mirror in her bathroom so she can take care of herself. There's no need to go further afield here.

Comment: It's conceivable that it means "I want to be able to look at my own reflection without being ashamed of myself" but not likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simplest interpretation is that Rachel mentions the mirror as providing a literal second person that she can meet, because that is being 'good to myself' compared to her previous experiences with real people; "...if I feel lonely I can alway talk with my reflection".
This seems a tragic-comedy, sarcastic expression overall, perhaps ironically hiding an appeal to Martin to help her try a relationship again.
I also feel that this mirror-idiom is so bleak that it emphasises the degree of loneliness that she really feels.

Comment: This actually gives more sense to the context. If I need to translate it is it preferred to keep it  literally or not. If not how can you paraphrase it to deliver the meaning intended?

Comment: In the target language, I'd think how (or if) I'd tell a potential partner that I was lonely but shy of new relationships, but that because my current coping methods weren't really satisfactory I could be available...
I'd start by doing it literally, then I'd think about idioms, humor, street slang, then refine this to match the context of the target writing project.